# In Linux kernel TCP implement, Why "sk_acceptq_is_full" use '>' rather than '>='?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, linux-kernel

My linux kernel version is 4.4.0.

Here is my code snippet

```c
    int listenfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(50001);

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    listen(listenfd, 2); // just listen, never accept
    while(1)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }
```

I expect it can only accomplish **2** TCP 3-shakehand process because the **backlog** argument in `listen` is **2**.

However, when I do a test, the result is **3** rather than **2**

So, I had a glance over the source code.

In `tcp_input.c`

```
int tcp_conn_request(struct request_sock_ops *rsk_ops,
             const struct tcp_request_sock_ops *af_ops,
             struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    // code omitted
    if (sk_acceptq_is_full(sk) && inet_csk_reqsk_queue_young(sk) > 1) { 
    NET_INC_STATS_BH(sock_net(sk), LINUX_MIB_LISTENOVERFLOWS);
    goto drop;
    }
     // code omitted
}
```

it use `sk_acceptq_is_full` to see if the accept queue is full

```c
static inline bool sk_acceptq_is_full(const struct sock *sk)
{
    return sk->sk_ack_backlog > sk->sk_max_ack_backlog;
}
```

I knew that the `sk->sk_ack_backlog` is the number of complete TCP 3-shakehand that is not `accept()` by user.And `sk->sk_max_ack_backlog` is the argument is `listen()`

So It seems that i found out the reason why  result is **3** rather than **2**,

But what puzzles me is that why he use `>` rather than `>=` to judge the queue is full ?  Isn't more reasonable to use `>=` ?

the new version(5.0.9) kernel is same.